# Safest and most secure way for backing up private data

Tags: pgp, backup

Here is what happened, I first collected my data into one folder,`tar`'d it, encrypted it with `gpg`, put it in truecrypt container, and after that started to copy the container to another place, but before copying got to the halfway mark:

> Input/output error

so I opened the container and started to copy gpg files out again, but there was one file that didn't finish coping, so I started to decrypt it, but there was a problem down there.

> rezx@rezx-desktop:/media/truecrypt8$ gpg Backup4
>
> gpg: CAMELLIA256 encrypted data
>
> gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
>
> gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
>
> gpg: Backup4: unknown suffix
>
> Enter new filename [Backup4]: Backup4.tar
>
> gpg: Backup4: read error: Input/output error
>
> gpg: Problem reading source (257056845 bytes remaining)
>
> gpg: handle plaintext failed: file read error
>
> gpg: mdc_packet with invalid encoding
>
> gpg: decryption failed: invalid packet
>
> uioiu@uioiu-desktop:/media/truecrypt8$

I don't want to get back what has been lost up there, as I still hve unencrypt copy, but such a problem gets me back to my first question "what is the safest & most secure way to back up my data?" and some other questions.

1. If the .gpg file was corrupted shouldn't it be encrypted by truecrypt. If yes, how come I can't copy the container.
2. How safe is a `tar` archive and a `gpg` encrypted file for long term archives and big files because if something bad happened, it may be with `tar` archive or with `gpg` as it's not with truecrypt, the rest of file is ok.
3. What is the safest and most secure way to archive a backup for my private data. I can't handle losing it because there would be some movies/pictures that can't be taken again, since funny/embarrassing/happy/sad moments don't happen twice. I don't have a time machine to go back and film baby first step/word, so it has to be safe and secure. There is some poetry/thoughts/films/pictures/???/ that I didn't want any stranger to see, but I like to watch it with who i want family/friends.

Comment: "i didnt want any stranger to see but i like to review it and share it with who i want", By definition, sharing with who you want also include a potential share with stranger. (Suppose the one whom you share your data with, will then share it to someone else, unknown to you)

Comment: no, u got me wrong i mean watch it with my family or friends no share it online..

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't need that much encryption. TrueCrypt provides enought security. Simply create a truecrypt volume and put all your sensitive files inside it.

To get best protection, use the passphrase + keyfile combination. And make sure to make backups: backup of the truecrypt container and of the keyfile, too. The more important the files are, the more you should make backups, perhaps some of them in internet, with those cloud-storage-services.

To share something with someone: put the file inside a .zip file, password protect, and give it to the person you want, with the password. But remember that the person might give a copy of the file to anyone.

Comment: first i never send my private files to any one even if my self on a strange pc mean never open my files/email on strange computer even if it for my brother not that i dont trust him but i dont trust his pc safety, second truecrypt is wonderfull for my pc encryption but if i gona put this files on cd or upload it to public online drive i want it to die with me and never access by any one, i could blackmailed by it, happen to alot :(